# Oracle 11g/or12c

Tags: oracle

Can anyone tell  me steps to install Oracle 11g or 12c(anyone) on my ubuntu machine 13.10.

I tried so many times,googling is also not working in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install Oracle 12C database on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit OS.

Following are the steps.

The "/etc/hosts" file must contain a fully qualified name for the server.
    
Sample file is as follows
    cat /etc/hosts
    127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
    192.168.1.100   lab.home.network    lab

Run following commands to update your Ubuntu OS

```
#sudo apt-get update
#sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Restart machine

```
#sudo init 6
```

Again check if there is any update

```
#sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Run following to install dependencies

```
#sudo apt-get -y install alien binutils build-essential cpp-4.4 debhelper g++-4.4 gawk gcc-4.4 gcc-4.4-base gettext html2text lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 intltool-debian ksh lib32bz2-dev lib32z1-dev libaio-dev libaio1 libbeecrypt7 libc6 libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 libelf-dev libelf1 libltdl-dev libltdl7 libmotif4 libodbcinstq4-1 libodbcinstq4-1:i386 libqt4-core libqt4-gui libsqlite3-0 libstdc++5 libstdc++6 libstdc++6-4.4-dev lsb lsb-core lsb-cxx lsb-desktop lsb-graphics lsb-qt4 make odbcinst pax po-debconf rpm rpm-common sysstat unixodbc unixodbc-dev unzip
```

Create oracle user and groups for installation

```
#sudo addgroup oinstall
#sudo addgroup dba
#sudo addgroup nobody
#sudo usermod -g nobody nobody
#sudo useradd -g oinstall -G dba -p password -d /home/oracle -s /bin/bash oracle
#sudo mkdir /home/oracle
#sudo chown -R oracle:dba /home/oracle
#sudo mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle
#sudo mkdir -p /u01/binaries
#sudo chown -R oracle:dba /u01
```

The following steps must be performed to set the password for the "oracle" user.

```
#sudo passwd oracle
```

Symbolic link, Kernel parameters and shell configuration as per the Oracle 12c Documentation. Make ourself as Red Hat by running following command

```
#echo 'Red Hat Linux release 6' | sudo tee -a  /etc/redhat-release
```

We need to create some soft links to start the installation. To do so run the following commands,

```
#sudo mkdir /usr/lib64
#sudo ln -s /etc /etc/rc.d
#sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 /lib64/
#sudo ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk
#sudo ln -s /usr/bin/basename /bin/basename
#sudo ln -s /usr/bin/rpm /bin/rpm
#sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a /usr/lib64/
#sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread_nonshared.a /usr/lib64/
#sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /lib64/
#sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/lib64/
```

To change the shell configuration for oracle user run following commands

```
#sudo cp /etc/security/limits.conf /etc/security/limits.conf.original
#echo "#Oracle 12C shell limits:" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
#echo "oracle soft nproc 2048" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
#echo "oracle hard nproc 16384"| sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
#echo "oracle soft nofile 1024" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
#echo "oracle hard nofile 65536" | sudo tee -a /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Run following command to change the kernel parameters

```
#echo "#" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "# Oracle 12C entries" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "fs.aio-max-nr=1048576" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "fs.file-max=6815744" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "kernel.shmall=2097152" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "kernel.shmmni=4096" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "kernel.sem=250 32000 100 128" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=9000 65500" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "net.core.rmem_default=262144" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "net.core.rmem_max=4194304" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "net.core.wmem_default=262144" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "net.core.wmem_max=1048586" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
#echo "kernel.shmmax=1073741824" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Note: kernel.shmmax = max possible value, e.g. size of physical memory in bytes. In my case machine is having 2GB so we are specifying 1GB. Adjust the parameter as per your configuration

Load new kernel parameters, by running following,

```
#sudo sysctl -p
```

We need to do changes in start-up script, run following commands as root

```
#mkdir /etc/rc.d
#for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 S
#do sudo ln -s /etc/rc$i.d /etc/rc.d/rc$i.d 
#done
```

Download Oracle 12C database from Oracle Download Center for Linux.
I have downloaded both the zip in /u01/binaries.
Login as an oracle user

We need to extract both the zip to start the installation. To unzip run,

```
#cd /u01/binaries
#unzip linuxamd64_12c_database_1of2.zip
#unzip linuxamd64_12c_database_2of2.zip
#chown -Rf oracle:dba /u01/binaries
```

Start installation using following command

```
#/u01/binaries/database/runInstaller -ignoreSysPrereqs
```

And complete the setup there after. Remember Ubuntu is not certifies OS for Oracle Database. 
In case of any issues follow below post of mine.

[How to install Oracle 12C Database On Ubuntu 13.10 64Bit](http://www.techienote.com/2014/04/how-to-install-oracle-12c-enterprise-edition-database-ubuntu-13-10.html%22%20How%20to%20install%20Oracle%2012C%20Database%20On%20Ubuntu%2013.10%2064Bit%22)